# Is there a way to instantiate DeviceClient without a connection string in java [Azure-IoT-Hub] edge module?

Tags: azure-iot-hub

Is there a way to instantiate DeviceClient without a connection string in java? 
Maybe with the use of ModuleClient object and DeviceClientConfig?
I do not want to set the DeviceConnectionString in the environment variables.

Comment: I do recommend to use a leaf certificate.

Comment: Thanks @RomanKiss, Could you please provide any links which has some sample?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that forces you to use environment variables to store your device connection string, even though that's what the code samples are using. You are free to store the connection string in whatever system suits you best (encrypted local data store, database, config file, secure module, ...).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am developing a java edge module with spring-boot-webflux. I need to to some C2D messaging. The problem with passing on the Device connection string to instantiate the DeviceClient object is that the DeviceConnectionString changes on the azure portal often (for eg:- once in 4 days). Then I need to again take the new connection string from portal and update it.

Comment: Are you sure about the fact that the connection string changes once in 4 days? What subscription are you on? What exactly it changes inside the connection string, because the hub and device name should be the same. Is it the SharedAccessKey that is different?

Comment: Dear @Amicis, I have provisioned the edge device using TPM. Only the SharedAccessKey changes but not exactly after every 4 days but whenever the edge device is restarted or approximately after 4 or 5 days even if it is not restarted. Now I am trying to instantiate DeviceClient exacly like it is mentioned in this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59793319/connecting-to-azure-iot-hub-using-tpm), I am also getting the same exception "activateIdentityKey first before signing"